# JSF I'm Losing Session State When Changing From Managed To CDI

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi, managed-bean, session-scope

Edit: This is an epic face palm situation. Wrong import for SessionScoped. So tired last night while checking it I was sure I was using enterprise sessionscoped import while I was still using faces sessionscoped import. I'm leaving this up as an aid to doofuses like me. :)

---

It is early in this project. After implementing up to this point with managed beans, I changed my managed beans to CDI beans as this seems to be the latest consensus on the best way to do things *But this has broken previously working code.* I cannot for the life of me figure out why. Help and advice is appreciated.

Happy Path (Summary... detail below code extracts)

*If user not logged in, show login or register links.

If user logged in show user preferences or logout links.*

Now Crappy Path with CDI (I don't blame CDI)

*If user not logged in, show login or register links.

If user logged in still see login or register links. (bad, bad app)*

The objects involved are

1. a facelet menu panel (with a primefaces login dialog... I don't think this has any thing to do with it but included for completeness) with render attributes if logged in or not,
2. a session scoped user bean,
3. a request scoped authentication bean to log the user in and out.

Objects used listed below. Implemented as CDI beans.

facelet

```
<h:panelGroup id="loginPanel" rendered="#{!user.loggedIn}">
    Show login buttons and stuff
</h:panelGroup>

 <h:panelGroup id="logoutPanel" rendered="#{user.loggedIn}">
    Show logout buttons and stuff
</h:panelGroup
```

authentication bean

```
@Named(value = "webAuthenticationBean") //formerly managedbean
@RequestScoped
public class WebAuthenticationBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject private UserBean user; //formerly a managed property which worked
...
request.login(uername, password);
user.setuserdata(username); // sessionscoped user state here used to check login state among other things later.
...
return(true) // they are now logged in
```

user bean

```
@Named(value = "user") //formerly managedbean
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private UserService userService; //stateless session bean
    private userInfo = new UserInfo(); // keeps user state and can be used as a DTO/VO

@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
    //sets default state to "guest user". This is NOT a logged in state
    }

public void setuserdata(String username){
     userInfo = userService.getUserInfo(username);
    // method called from WebAuthenticationBean 
    // sets the user state to a non-guest user (they're logged in).
    // I can see in debug mode that this is being called and retrieving
   //  the user data from the database and setting "userInfo"
}

public void isLoggedIn() throws InvalidUserException{
    // checks state to see if they are logged in, basically a bit more than are they still a guest or not
   returns (true) if logged in 
    returns (false) if not logged in
    // this worked with managed beans
}
...
```

So here is the actual use case when I watch in debug mode:

Happy Path (prior to change to CDI bean)

1)  User navigates to the welcome page
2)   the user bean is queried to see if they are logged in (user.loggedIn in the facelet).
3)  userbean checks logged in state. If they are still a guest they aren’t logged in.
4)  They are identified as a guest so isLoggedIn() returns false.
5)  Login button is shown.
6)  User requests logs in
7)  authentication bean begins login process: request.login returns successfully
8)  authenticationbean sets user data: user.setuserdata(username) returns successfuly.
9)  authentication bean loginMethod returns (they are logged userprincipal on the server)

Alternate (crappy) path branch here (happy path continues)

10) The menu rechecks login state (user.loggedIn)
11) userbean checks for appropriate state and sees they are valid non guest user
12) userbean returns (true) they are logged in
13) menu shows logout button

Crappy Path (what happens after I changed these to CDI beans)

10) The menu rechecks login state (user.loggedIn)
11) userbean checks for appropriate state and sees they are a guest  //the updated user state seems to have disappeared from this user in this session.
12) userbean returns (false) they are not logged in //but they are
13) menu shows login button // they can’t login anyway since the server already sees them as logged in, in this session (ServletException: Attempt to re-login while the user identity already exists).

Why using managedbeans would I be able to see the userbean maintain its data in session scope but with cdi beans it does not? I am stumped. I’ll switch back to managed beans if I have to, it isn’t a big issue, but I would like to find out what I messed up.

---

I added some debugging code in the init method of the UserBean, and it appears as if the system is treating the SessionScoped UserBean as if it were RequestScoped. That is it is initializing on every call.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    if (userInfo == null) {
        userInfo = new UserInfoDTO();
        userInfo.setUserName("Guest");
        List<String> guestGroup = Arrays.asList(CoreUserGroupType.GUEST.toString());
        userInfo.setUserGroups(guestGroup);
        System.out.println("UserBean.init INSIDE Init If Statement");
    }
    System.out.println("UserBean.init OUTSIDE Init If Statement");
}
```

If it were really acting like it was SessionScoped the userInfo object would not be null every time and the 'if' statement would not be executed every time. But it is executing on every call to UserBean.  So this is at the crux of the problem. As a matter of fact if it acted like it were in session scope it would not hit the init method at all on every call as it would still be initialized.

Am I not creating a sessionscoped bean properly? It would appear so, but I don't see how. As mentioned, this code ran fine when defined as a managedbean.

Answer (score 2):

changed to the correct sessionscoped import and all is well. nothing hurt but my pride.

Comment: I reckon we've all done it and it's good that you came clean.

Comment: It's confusing that Java EE has those two annotations. Last I heard is that the faces one will be deprecated. This can take a long time though...